# file_get_contents not waiting

Tags: php, rest

I'm using a PHP call to a REST service to retrieve information from the eXist XML database, running on localhost, capturing the results with `file_get_contents()`, and using those results to populate a drop-down list in a query form. I thought that `file_get_contents()` was supposed to wait automatically for complete results, but apparently it doesn't; sometimes the list is fully populated and sometimes it's truncated. The truncation happens at various locations, and reloading the page (rerunning the PHP, and therefore the REST call) usually fixes it, although sometimes not on the first try.

If I've diagnosed the problem correctly as a matter of `file_get_contents()` not waiting for results, can anyone advise me about how to fix it? Or is there an alternative explanation? Here's the relevant snippet from the PHP:

```
$getPersonNamesQuery = <<< EOQ1
{for \$i in doc('/db/genealogy/genealogy.xml')//person[not(.//firstName eq "unknown")]
    order by string-join(\$i/name/*," ")
    return
        {normalize-space(concat(
        \$i/name/firstName,
        " ",
        if (\$i/name/epithet) then concat("â",\$i/name/epithet,"â) else "",
        " ",
        \$i/name/patronymic," ",
        if (not(\$i/@origin eq "Rus'" or \$i/@origin eq "unknown")) then concat("of ",\$i/@origin) else ""
        ))}
    }
EOQ1;
$contents = "http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/genealogy?_howmany=10000&_wrap=no&_query=" . urlencode($getPersonNamesQuery);
$personNames = file_get_contents($contents);
```

Thanks,

David

Comment: file_get_contents DOES wait for a response. If it's returning quickly, it's because the requested resource finished quickly or something caused the connection to end early.

Comment: It's not that it's returning quickly, it's that I'm not getting the complete results, that is, that the return is (sometimes) truncated. If I've misdiagnosed the problem (certainly possible!), where else might I look for an explanation?

Comment: Use something that gives better diagnostics, like curl. file_get_contents is somewhat monolithic and very difficult to debug. But in short, if the data it's returning is truncated, that's because whatever's sending it, or the network, is causing truncation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting complete results when I talk directly to eXist, not going through PHP, so I had ruled out the REST call itself as the source of the problem. I'll look there. The problem is intermittent (although pretty frequent, but sometimes I get complete results, sometimes I don't, and the truncation can happen at different places), and because I can't replicate it  I'm having trouble testing. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened with me, I was using http_build_query to build query string, and the result of file_get_contents and cURL both were responding prematurely. Passing the complete query string without http_build_query in both of the functions resulted in a success. Weird!

This resulted is truncated data:

```
$pUrl=array('username'=>'_username_',
            'variable'=>'value',
            'variable2'=>'value2',
            'variable3'=>'value3');
$cURL=http_build_query($pUrl);
print_r(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/api/?$cURL"));
```

This returned the complete data everytime:

```
print_r(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/api/?username=_username_&variable=value&...."));
```